# python multiple dict compare

Tags: python, dictionary, compare

I have one dict and want to compare with 3 more dict. 
If key does not exist in any of the 3 dict, then to create a new dict with that key, value pair, Also, skip if the key and value both match in any of the 3 dict, and if key exist but value is different then create a one more dict.

```
a={'a':1,'b':2,'c':3,'d':4}
b={'a':10,'b':20}
c={'p':100,'q':200,'c':300}
d={'a':1000,'x':2000,'c':3}
```

After comparing dict a with b,c and d. The result should be     `p_dict = {'d':4}`     and     `q_dict = {'a':1,'b':2}`

I am thinking for multiple for loops but it will create 2 more dict after comparing dict a and b and it will complicate process. Does anyone have better idea?

Comment: @PaulC: Why use a URL shortener if the new URL is longer than the original one?

Comment: good question. I think because it looks nice. I just copied it from the other tab I had open. No particular reason to use that. And I'll use the "normal" one next time!

Comment: @Tim, I have updated the correct format,but you got it already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution for Python 3.3. This also works in Python 2.7, but there I would use `.iteritems()` instead of `.items()`:

```
>>> a = {"a":1, "b":2, "c":3, "d":4}
>>> b = {"a":10, "b":20}
>>> c = {"p":100, "q":200, "c":300}
>>> d = {"a":1000, "x":2000, "c":3}
>>> p_dict = {k:v for k,v in a.items() 
...               if not any(k in dicts for dicts in (b,c,d))}
>>> p_dict
{'d': 4}
>>> q_dict = {k:v for k,v in a.items()
...               if any(k in dicts for dicts in (b,c,d))
...               and not any(dicts.get(k)==v for dicts in (b,c,d))}
>>> q_dict
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

This assumes that none of the values in your dicts are `None`.

Comment: Both `items()` and `iteritems()` will work in 2.7, actually. Neither will work in earlier versions since they don't have dict comprehensions.

Comment: Thanks Tim. I used b.update(c) and b.update(d), so now I just have dict a and b to compare.

Comment: @Junuxx: Thanks; I have clarified my answer (I hope) :)

Comment: @user922898: You must not do that! This changes the logic of your program. Take the following: `b = {"a":1, "b":20}`. Now, according to your specs, `q_dict` should not contain `"a"` any more because it's contained in `b` *and*  has the same values as in `a`. But once you do `b.update(d)`, you overwrite `b`'s values whose keys are present in `d`. Therefore, `b["a"]` now is 1000, and therefore, `q_dict` will contain `"a": 1`.

Comment: Thanks Tim. You are right about the logic.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a 2.x (not using dict comprehension) solution based on Tim Pietzcer's approach:

```
In [680]: dicts=[b,c,d]

In [681]: p_dict=dict([(k,v) for k,v in a.iteritems()
                      if not any(k in di for di in dicts)])

In [682]: p_dict
Out[682]: {'d': '4'}

In [683]: q_dict=dict([(k,v) for k,v in a.iteritems() 
                      if any(k in di for di in dicts)
                      and not any(di.get(k)==v for di in dicts) ])

In [684]: q_dict
Out[684]: {'a': '1', 'b': '2'}
```