# python compare two dict lists and show missing items

Tags: python

I have two lists

```
list_1 =  [{ "id" : 1, "name" : "kitten"}, { "id" : 2, "name" : "puppy"}, { "id" : 2, "name" : "mouse"}]

list_2 =  [{ "id" : 1, "name" : "kitten"}, { "id" : 2, "name" : "mouse"}]
```

I would like to have a new list created that shows items missing from list_2. so list_3 for example would show

```
list 3 = { "id" : 2, "name" : "puppy"}
```

Would someone be able to help me achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python multiple dict compare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12712995/python-multiple-dict-compare)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
In [1]: list_1 =  [{ "id" : 1, "name" : "kitten"}, { "id" : 2, "name" : "puppy"}, { "id" : 2, "name" : "mouse"}]
   ...:
   ...: list_2 =  [{ "id" : 1, "name" : "kitten"}, { "id" : 2, "name" : "mouse"}]

In [2]: [i for i in list_1 if i not in list_2]
Out[2]: [{'id': 2, 'name': 'puppy'}]
```